# Couchbase Testcontainer connection timed out on when run on Windows

Tags: testcontainers

We are running spring boot tests with Couchbase TestContainers to test Couchbase integration.

We connect to the Couchbase testcontainer using the following code :

```
BucketDefinition bucketDefinition = new BucketDefinition("orders");
    DockerImageName myImage = DockerImageName.parse(
                    "org.domain:38100/couchbase:enterprise-6.6.1")
            .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("couchbase/server");
    couchbaseContainer =
            new CouchbaseContainer(myImage).withBucket(
                    bucketDefinition);
    couchbaseContainer.start();
    DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .bootstrapCarrierDirectPort(couchbaseContainer.getMappedPort(11210))
            .bootstrapCarrierSslPort(couchbaseContainer.getMappedPort(11207))
            .bootstrapHttpDirectPort(couchbaseContainer.getMappedPort(8091))
            .bootstrapHttpSslPort(couchbaseContainer.getMappedPort(18091))
            .build();
    final CouchbaseCluster couchbaseCluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env);
    couchbaseCluster.authenticate(couchbaseContainer.getUsername(), couchbaseContainer.getPassword());
    bucket = couchbaseCluster.openBucket(bucketDefinition.getName());
```

This works fine on linux when we run it through the IDE or through maven. However when we run the same code on windows we get the following error :

```
14:21:17.979 [cb-io-1-8] WARN com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint - [172.17.0.3:8093][QueryEndpoint]: Socket connect took longer than specified timeout: connection timed out: /172.17.0.3:8093
14:21:17.979 [cb-io-1-1] WARN com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint - [172.17.0.3:8093][QueryEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint on reconnect attempt 30, retrying with delay 4096 MILLISECONDS: com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /172.17.0.3:8093
14:21:17.979 [cb-io-1-8] WARN com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint - [172.17.0.3:8093][QueryEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint on reconnect attempt 29, retrying with delay 4096 MILLISECONDS: com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /172.17.0.3:8093
```

What can be the possible reason for this? Is their something that needs to configured on windows docker or windows to make the containers work?

Answer (score 0):

Try "withEnabledServices"
at least this works for me on Windows.

```
new CouchbaseContainer(myImage).withEnabledServices(CouchbaseService.QUERY);
```

Indeed, there are more services (KV, INDEX) etc. Depends on your needs,.